# Sending and receiving date time ticks between client and server by SignalR gives different value after transmission

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr, long-integer, azure-table-storage

I've made a chatbox using SignalR and an ASP.NET MVC application, all the messages that are send, are stored in an Azure storage service table. For the `RowKey` and the `PartitionKey` I'll that is equal to `DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()`.

For saving the entries into the table, I've no problem also deleting a entry I've <strike>no</strike> problem. However, no problem isn't 100% true.

For removing a message *(without refreshing the page)*, I send also the ticks back to the client and store that in the `data-key`-attribute. If the user pressed on the delete button, the value of that attribute send I back to the server.

The problem I've got now is that the tick that the server received for remove that message is different than the ticks in the Azure table. Here you've my code in the hub.

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{
    long key = DateTime.Now.Ticks; // → key is equal to 635991085278582583

    Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(key, name, message);               
    _chatService.AddMessage(new ChatMessage(key, name, message));   
}

public void Remove(string key)
{
    _chatService.RemoveMessage(key); // → key is equal to 635991085278582500
    Clients.All.BroadcastRemoved(key);
}
```

Here is the code in the class ChatMessage:

```
public class ChatMessage : TableEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ChatMessage()
    {
    }

    public ChatMessage(string partitionKey, string rowKey) : base(partitionKey, rowKey)
    { 
    }

    public ChatMessage(long key, string name, string message)
    {
        PartitionKey = key.ToString();
        RowKey = key.ToString();
        UserName = name;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

After debugging my code I've seen that I've received 6359910852785825**00** on the server but the `PartitionKey` in the table is 6359910852785825**83**. So you can see the keys are different and I've got the exception.

---

For curious people here you've my JQuery code:

```
var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

chat.client.BroadcastMessage = function (key, name, message) {

    message = encode(message);
    name = encode(name);

    var discussionpane = $("#discussion").eq(0);

    discussionpane.append('<div class="message" data-key="' + key + '"><p><b>' + name + ':</b>&nbsp;' + message + '</p><p>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet"></span></p></div>');

    initEvents();
};

chat.client.BroadcastRemoved = function (key) {
    $('.message[data-key=' + key + ']').addClass("removed");
    $('.message[data-key=' + key + '] p').html("");
    initEvents();
};

$('#message').focus();

$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('#sendmessage').click(function () {

        var text = $('#message').val();

        if (text != "") {
            chat.server.send("@(User.Identity.GetUserName())", text);
            $('#message').val('').focus();
        }
    });

    initEvents();
});

function initEvents() {

    $(".message .glyphicon-trash").click(function () {

        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        parent.addClass("removed");
        chat.server.remove(parent.data("key"));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it! I send now the long values as a string to the client. The value I receive on the client now equal to what the server has send.